# Watermark Effect to a View in android

Tags: android, watermark

I'm developing an android app, I need to add a watermark effect (of an image) to a EditText of several lines. What is the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: I hope it helps you https://github.com/MakoFeng/WatermarkDemo

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/23/image-processing-watermarking-on-the-fly/) is a great tutorial on android image processing. Below is the source code from the site

```
public static Bitmap mark(Bitmap src, String watermark, Point location, Color color, int alpha, int size, boolean underline) {
int w = src.getWidth();
int h = src.getHeight();
Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(color);
paint.setAlpha(alpha);
paint.setTextSize(size);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setUnderlineText(underline);
canvas.drawText(watermark, location.x, location.y, paint);

return result;
}
```